# PostgreSQL: Simple IN vs IN values performace

Tags: postgresql, performance

We have queries with IN filters with long list of INT values

Sometimes, they running extremely slow, and I have found suggestion to use syntax

```
Field IN (VALUES(1465), (1478), ...
```

Instead of

```
Field IN (1465, 1478, ...
```

On some cases it helps, but on other it makes query running 1000+ times slower

So the issue is:

- some queries much faster with simple IN
- some queries much faster with IN + VALUES

Here is explain on case when it’s extremely slow:

```
->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.78..9.62 rows=385 width=4)
       Group Key: ""*VALUES*"".column1" 
                   ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*""  (cost=0.00..4.81 rows=385 width=4)"
```

What is the right way to pass long INT values list to IN filter?

I am using PostgreSQL 13.1 on Ubuntu

Comment: There's no universal "right way"; you need to tune each query on its own.

Comment: Can you show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a case that is too slow and for a case that isn't?